# Penalty Boxの表示がおかしい

Tags: バグ, 完了

ユーザーが一時的に停止（Penalty Box）された際の表示がおかしいです。

> **このアカウントは[一時的に停止されています](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sHCV.png)（）。一時停止は6日後に終了します。**

（）の中に何か重要な情報が書かれる予定で、それが抜け落ちていないか気になりました。

ユーザーページ最上部のスクリーンショット:

> [image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: 一時停止を含むプロフィールは公開情報で誰でも見られる状態にあるものの、"説明に必要な部分のみ" をキャプチャした方が無難かと思います。(受け取りようによっては晒上げのような印象になりかねないので、後から別のトラブルとなる可能性も)

Comment: 該当ページで現象、及びその修正まで確認できましたので、不要になった部分は編集しました。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。Penalty Box自体、初めて見る機能でした。なので、このメッセージがどこに表示されるのかが伝わらなければ質問が成立しないと思っての参考画像でした。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 翻訳文字列

私による翻訳ミスかも知れません。 https://ja.traducir.win/strings/1229

原文は、

> This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.

でしたが、`$reason$`が空になるとは思わなかったので、丸かっこに入れて、

> このアカウントは$linkStart$一時的に停止されています$linkEnd$（$reason$）。一時停止は$penaltyEndDate$に終了します。

としました。これにより本サイトでは、

> このアカウントは一時的に停止されています（ クール ダウンのため）。一時停止は6日後に終了します。

となっています（余計な空白が入っていますので、これも修正しなければなりません）が、メタサイトでは `$reason$` が空のようで、この現象が起きています。`$reason$` がメタサイトでは空になる、というのが意図された仕様ならば、翻訳ミスです。

#### 翻訳文字列で丸かっこを使用した理由

`$reason$` を丸かっこに入れた理由は、ここに設定される文字列にどのような可能性が有るか不明であり、文章の一部に当て込むと英語では自然であっても、日本語では破綻する、という可能性が有るからです。しかし再考すると、`$reason$` 自体に丸かっこが含まれる可能性も有りますし、あまり良くありませんでした。

#### 修正

私がこれを修正するには、

- メタで `$reason$` が空になるのは仕様か
- `$reason$` にはどのような文が入る可能性が有るのか

の2点が情報として必要です。情報無しで良い翻訳を思い付いた方は、修正していただければと思います。

Comment: "クール ダウンのため" の余分な空白については翻訳を更新しておきました。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。「クール ダウンのため」の前にも謎のスペースが有るのですが、これはたぶんプログラム側で入れてしまっているので対処できないですね。
このスペースを入れる処理の存在は、プログラム側では `$reason$` が空である可能性を考慮している事を意味しますので、やはり `$reason$` が空になるのは仕様かも知れませんね。
あまり推測しても仕方ないですが。

Comment: "前にも謎のスペースが有る" については、英語の分かち書きを前提にした結果のようなので、現状の仕組みだと翻訳で対応するのは難しそうですね。

Comment: メタで `$reason$` が空になるのは[仕様](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280130/314875)だったようです。丸かっこを使用された理由などもご説明くださりありがとうございました。MSEではタグの変更などが進み、コミュニティ全体で学びがありました。翻訳案など、いつもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

該当ユーザーのプロフィールをメインサイト上で確認してもらうと分かりますが、`( )` 内には「一時停止の理由」が表示されるはずです。

なお、原文の英語では以下のような表記になるようです。"to cool down" の部分が理由の一つとして `$reason$` にセットされるのでしょう。

> This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Apr 27 '24 at 7:54

改善案として、mjy さんの回答も踏まえると `()` を使わずに例えば以下のように翻訳すればより自然になりそうです。(`$reason$` が空の場合も不自然にならないはず)

**修正候補:** (翻訳案として入力済み)

```
このアカウントは $reason$$linkStart$ 一時的に停止されています$linkEnd$。一時停止は $penaltyEndDate$ に終了します。
```

メタ上のプロフィール表示で `$reason$` が空になるのは仕様っぽい気もしますが、念のため確認が必要ですかね。(スタッフじゃないと分からない部分です)

Comment: この翻訳が、現状ベストかも知れないですね。
`$reason$` が例えば「because 〜」のような文になり得る場合は「to 〜」に比べ破綻する可能性が高そうですが、これは我々には対処が難しいですから。

Comment: [仕様](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367509/7493042)でした。修正候補をあげてくださりどうもありがとうございました。